# wxpython image doesn't fit on screen

Tags: wxpython

My computer allows a maximum resolution of 1366x768.  I have a massive series of images that are 1024x768.  Everything I bring them up in wxpython the image always gets cut off the bottom of the screen.  How do I resize the image so it will fit entirely on the screen...obviously the width isn't an issue just the height of the image is causing trouble.  By the time the frame of the gui gets created I lose about 1/4 of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use some scaling code, like this:

```
img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
# scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
W = img.GetWidth()
H = img.GetHeight()
if W > H:
    NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize
    NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize * H / W
else:
    NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize
    NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize * W / H
img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)
```

Then once I have it scaled appropriately, I add it to a wx.StaticBitmap:

```
self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                  wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
```

Try setting **self.PhotoMaxSize** to various amounts until you find the optimal size or you could use wx.GetDisplaySize() and derive a height based on that.

You might also find this tutorial helpful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/